# Have jQuery fire Ajax request when when back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers, session-variables, browser-history

I have a page with 80+ dynamically generated input boxes, when the user submits the form to another .php page and one of the inputs contains a value that is not numeric, it will send them back to the inputs page using: `<?php header("Location: javascript:history.back()"); ?>`, at the same time it registers the error in a session variable. The reason why I'm using javascript:history.back(), is because it stores the values that were in the form, even when you press the back button. But because it is caching the page I can't output the error in the same .php script, so I added a an element and some Ajax code. The Ajax code retrieves another file called error.php, this contains:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache"); 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) 
{
    echo $_SESSION['error'];
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
?>
```

This is retrieved when the page is loaded on it own, but not when `history.back()` is used, it looks like the following isn't firing:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("#error p").load("error.php"); 
 });
 </script>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
 Justin

Comment: I know this probably isn't what you want to hear, but this is a pretty unreliable way to do form validation.  You are depending on the browser to do some work that it may or may not do, namely: `because it stores the values that were in the form, even when you press the back button`.  A much better way would be to submit to the page like you are, but have php re-render the form (using an include most likely) and point out the errors to the user, populating the form with the data that you DO already have because the user just submitted it.

Comment: Furthermore (I'm saying a lot :) ), if you really want to keep the browser's history clean, I'd suggest submitting the form with ajax, and forwarding them along if it submits successfully.  Maybe I should've put these as answers....

Comment: Thanks, it's about time that I cleaned up some of my code... :D

Comment: `header("Location: javascript:history.back()");` Don't do this. Ever. I'm amazed it works in any browser - I'd bet money it doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: @Basiclife - Being amazed that something works is never a good reason for not doing it - nor should it be the premise for any advise you give to others ;) - javascript: urls are supported by all major browsers.

Comment: @Marcus Sorry, but you're just plain wrong. This is *not* good practice. From the [w3.org spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (section 14.30), the value should be a single absolute URI. You're assuming the browser will evaluate the returned javascript. What about browsers with JS disabled? What about IE6 which still has an annoyingly large market share? Just because it happens to work in some cases does not make it good practice!

Comment: @Basiclife: I never said it *was* a good practice, just a valid & fully supported one.  W3 specs are internally inconsistent, don't account for real world practices, but even still you proved my point because "should" != must. **All** major browsers support JS URL's.  Disabled JS accounts for <2% so even that doesn't justify NEVER using it. IE6 fully supports JS URL's (hell, even IE4 does.) But even still to say I'm "just plain wrong" because you think it only works in "some cases" only further proves my point. Sheesh, you are really sure about stuff you didn't know was even feasible yesterday

Comment: @Basiclife - last comment about this because it's becoming futile - From the w3.org spec (section 6.1.5) - the javascript: URL scheme is a fully supported protocol [1] (supported enough to be included in the HTML5 spec anyway.) But I suppose you're right and I'm just plain wrong.  I'll be sure to tell others that there is no justifiable scenario for using target="_blank" as well because that's not approved by the w3c under certain conditions - Please don't let my low SO rank fool you as it has no bearing on my expertise - 1: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#javascript-protocol

Comment: @Marcus Ignoring the slightly ranting nature of your above comments, there are still ample reasons not to do it - What about Web spiders, testing tools, etc. If you're happy to do it on your site(s), I'm not stopping you or telling you you shouldn't - But you're not going to convince me it's a good idea. I don't personally think advocating techniques that might work in some cases is a good way to go. For the record, I hadn't looked at your rep until you mentioned it and I formed my opinions of your "expertise" entirely from your comments.

Comment: @Basiclife - Actually you told me and everyone else on the internet to NEVER do it - "Don't do this. Ever. I'm amazed it works in any browser - I'd bet money it doesn't work in all browsers. – Basiclife"  And obviously you missed the reference points about it working in virtually every case except for maybe Mosaic. But alas  sorry for the ranting nature of my comments I took offense to the "You're just plain wrong" introduction regarding something I was perfectly correct about.  Send an email any address at marcuspope.com and I'd be glad to have a civil discussion with you on the topic.

Comment: It seems you're a little unclear. It's not good practice, I'd never recommend it to anyone - I'd recommend that others avoid it and if one of my team did this, it would fail a code review. That's my opinion and I believe it's a valid one. I have no doubt you disagree and you're welcome to do so but be aware that I've wasted enough of my time on this fruitless discussion and won't be responding again. If you feel the need to get a last post in telling me I'm wrong, knock yourself out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid submitting the form entirely and send the data via an AJAX call - the server could validate the data and send back either "success" or a list of validation errors.

If success, move on to the next URL (possibly specified alongside the success message)

If failed, modify the current page to indicate what the problems were. This avoids you having to re-create the whole form (as you never leave the page) but also allows for reliable server-side validation

Answer (score 1):

Using `header("Location: javascript:history.back()")` is generally ill-advised.

Use an absolute path i.e.

`header('Location: /forms/input.php');`

Comment: Sometimes an absolute path is not an option, and in those cases javascript: urls are completely supported and valid.

Comment: An absolute path is usually always an option and the best option, period. If you need to go back to the referring url, then use the referrer. If your using this technique and the user has Javascript disabled in their browser, your site is screwed. Overall using this technique is cheap, irritating to debug, badly degradable and terrible practice. No good coder would suggest on using inline `javascript:` as a redirect.

Comment: +1 I disagree wit the downvote - javascript URLs are a terrible idea. You're throwing together 2 unrelated technologies and trusting an unknown browser to sort it out. Doesn't sound like good practice to me

Comment: @Gary Green - I completely agree with your points as recommendations against doing it - except for the comment "No good coder would suggest on using inline javascript: as a redirect." because that is just a merritless personal attack .  Please don't take my downvote in vain - I simply think absolutes like "Don't ever use X" where X is both supported and solves for Y is bad advice - and any "good coder" would recognize that a panacea solution like "You should use absolute paths instead" are not always a solution.  If you want to change your verbiage I'd gladly up vote the answer.

Comment: @Basiclife - Please elaborate on why they are a terrible idea - they **are** related technologies (the fact that it works proves that point) - You are **always** "trusting" browsers to sort out everything related to web development even for simple things like a title tag - and as I previously pointed out, not sounding like a good practice to you is not a very good basis for recommending something to others because when your gut feelings are wrong, you have limited the scope of solutions in a world where solutions are often more important than your (read: everyone's) personal taste.

Comment: My last point on this - What do you do when the referrer is not an option? How do you mitigate the effects of referrer hijacking? Are javascript urls such a terrible idea that bookmarklets provide zero value and do not effectively solve a technical problem?  Is worrying about the 1% of users that disable javascript ALWAYS a reason to avoid a solution?  Is something many find trivial to debug, but irritates *you* a reason to avoid it absolutely?  Is a cheap & effective solution really a negative? Isn't "Don't ever use an absolute path it's just asking for trouble" equally bad advice?

Comment: (OFFTOPIC) and does anyone else find it frustrating that on SO you can't edit a comment after 5 minutes but you can copy the comment, delete it and re-comment with your edits?   :D  (there are a couple grammatical problems with the above comments because editing them to fit in the character limit left some cruft that I didn't intend)

Comment: 1. Crawlers won't know what day it is, 2. Javascript dependancy i.e. mobile platforms, popular Firefox addon NoScript a perfect example, 3. Javascript will run regardless of last site visited, 4. If your doing this over and over, your SEO will be screwed. Matt Cutts, from Google said, "I recommend absolute links because there's less chance for a spider to get confused." Basiclife, you and I have our own opinions this, although I don't think a downvote is warranted simply because it's not "your idea" of good advice, I respect you are entitled to your own opinions.

Comment: @Gary: All of your points are fair to add to the cons side of a pro/con list (most are situational, but still valid) - they are not germain to why I downvoted you. Even Cutts' opinion is vastly different from yours; he *recommends* using absolute URL's over other forms, OTOH you dictate that we NEVER use JS urls.  The former is good advice, the latter is not as the scenarios above point out.  Mobile platforms support them, the "popular" Firefox addon only accounts for about 1% of users. And SEO doesn't even apply to things like intranet web apps.  Change it to a "recommend" and I'll upvote it.

Comment: I've changed the wording to be less strong, but let's just look at the question at hand here. The poster is wondering why they are experiencing strange behaviour with using Javascript as a redirect when submitting a form -- they want to display the error, and as browsers generally cache the last page visited in history.back() -- which I might add is BROWSER DEPENDANT, there is no reliable way to know if the clients page was "reloaded" from memory or not, the solution to this is to not use a javascript redirect.

Comment: @Gary just to clarify, mine was the upvote - not sure who downvoted you. I wholeheartedly agree with you and thought the downvote was unjustified